# APP_ENV is set to "homestead" but app()->environment() says "local"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

On my `.env` file I can read:

```
APP_ENV=homestead
```

But if I run this with Psy Shell:

```
dd(app()->environment());
```

It displays : "homestead" (alright).

But if I run the same command from a controller method, It displays: "local"

Why?

Comment: could not reproduce this in a fresh laravel 5 setup

Comment: Ok, thanks :). Did you tried on homestead or another environment ?

Comment: I used artisan serve for this quick test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using homestead looking in homestead.yml file, there is a setting that sets environment variables for the server in /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf

```
variables:
- key: APP_ENV
  value: local
```

This setting takes precedence over .env file.